# T-SQL Custom Data Type as input parameter for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm quite new to T-SQL, I'm currently struggling with an input parameter for my stored procedure.

I want to pass a list of `SalesAreas` to my stored procedure. A `SalesArea` can have several countryIds and some bool values, imagine a class in C#.

I started to create my own data type to pass it into the stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE tIdList AS TABLE 
(
    ID INT NULL
);
GO

CREATE TYPE tSalesArea AS TABLE
(
    CountryIds tIdList NULL,
    IsLargeClient BIT NULL,
    IsSmallClient BIT NULL,
);
GO
```

In the stored procedure I want to pass in a list of `tSalesAreas`:

```
@SalesAreas tSalesArea READONLY
```

The problem: I cannot use my `tIdList` as a datatype for `tSalesArea`.

If I insert 2 Sales areas (1: countryIds 3,5; 2: countryId 7), it will look something like this:

```
Id | SalesAreaId | CountryId 
---+-------------+-----------
1  |     1       |     3
2  |     1       |     5
3  |     2       |     7
```

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a table type as a column (it is a table type) in sql server.

Instead, create the `tSalesArea` with columns needed to express your desired input.

```
create type tSalesArea as table (
    SaleAreaId int not null
  , CountryIds int not null
  , IsLargeClient bit null
  , IsSmallClient bit null
);
```

Comment: You could also pass in an XML parameter as a substitution for a table instead.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener Or Json, or a string you have to parse... There are always alternatives. However, table valued parameters are more semantically appropriate, and _usually_ perform much better than other options.